# Spring JMX Integration Issue

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I am having a java class like below,

```
public class MyImportService {
    Logger m_logger = Logger.getLogger(MyImportService.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("tService")
    private TService m_tservice;
    public Integer import(String zipFilePath,String userName) {
        int result = 0;
        File file = new File(zipFilePath);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(fileInputStream);
            m_taskservice.importT(zipInputStream, file.getName(), userName);
            m_logger.info("SuccessFully Imported"");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            result =  1;
            m_logger.error("Error while importing the file :",e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In my application context I am having the configuration like below.

```
<bean id="myImportService" class="com.service.MyImportService " />
    <bean id="exporter"
          class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
        <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry
                        key="application.MyApp:service=importTService"
                        value-ref="myImportService" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In case of exception its working fine, am getting a return value as 1. But in case the file is present am getting a runtime exception like.

**javax.management.MBeanException: RuntimeException thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation**

Please help me

Comment: Did you try debugging to determine why the "happy path" throws an exception? The exception message will surely include the detailed reason - and you didn't include this most important piece of the puzzle in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `catch (RuntimeException e)` catch block and print the stack trace so can you see what the underlying problem is.